# Sorting arrays in NumPy ascending from negative to positive axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have following code, i am having some difficulties with numpy arrays.

```
A= np.array(([[1, 2 ,25], [3, 4, 23], [2, 6,55], [9,7,78],[11,5,47]]),dtype='float')

u,udx = np.unique(A[:,0],return_index=True) # unique ascending frequencies from 1st column
A_sorted = A[udx,:] # adds sorted and unique 1st row into the array table

# fill the A-sorted with mag_lin and phase_rad in the 2nd adn 3rd column
A_sorted[:,1] = 10**(A_sorted[:,1]/10)  # Magnitude dB into linear

A_sorted[:,2] = np.pi/180 *A_sorted[:,2]

A_flip= np.flip(A_sorted,0) # flipping the arrays vertically;
A_flip[:,0]= -A_flip[:,0]
A_flip[:,2]= -A_flip[:,2]
H= np.concatenate(((A_flip,A_sorted)))
```

The ouput of this program is:

```
array([[-11.    ,   3.1623,  -0.8203],
       [ -9.    ,   5.0119,  -1.3614],
       [ -3.    ,   2.5119,  -0.4014],
       [ -2.    ,   3.9811,  -0.9599],
       [ -1.    ,   1.5849,  -0.4363],
       [ -1.    ,   1.5849,  -0.4363],
       [ -2.    ,   3.9811,  -0.9599],
       [ -3.    ,   2.5119,  -0.4014],
       [ -9.    ,   5.0119,  -1.3614],
       [-11.    ,   3.1623,  -0.8203]])
```

what i rather want is :

```
array([[-11.    ,   3.1623,  -0.8203],
       [ -9.    ,   5.0119,  -1.3614],
       [ -3.    ,   2.5119,  -0.4014],
       [ -2.    ,   3.9811,  -0.9599],
       [ -1.    ,   1.5849,  -0.4363],
       [  1.    ,   1.5849,   0.4363],
       [  2.    ,   3.9811,   0.9599],
       [  3.    ,   2.5119,   0.4014],
       [  9.    ,   5.0119,   1.3614],
       [ 11.    ,   3.1623,   0.8203]])
```

Somehow while doing

```
A_flip[:,0]= -A_flip[:,0]
A_flip[:,2]= -A_flip[:,2]
```

A_sorted's first and third colums are also set as negative, which i don't want. I am trying to plot  from -x to +x axis. Do you have any workaround for this problem?

Any help  is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with how numpy arrays are copied when assigning with =. A_flip and A_sorted are actually referring to the same object, so when you negate it, it applies to both variables (same object). The solution is to use the .copy() method to create a new object. So replace

`A_flip = np.flip(A_sorted,0)`

with

`A_flip = np.flip(A_sorted,0).copy()`

Comment: Hey Kyle, Thank You vey much, You are the saviour. Yeah, somehow i knew both of them were regarded as same object, just couldn't figure out how to solve it. Now its clear.